# Simple bootstrap classes not working

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I created a html page with a bootstrap but when I try to add responsive classes, they can not be seen on the case.

PS. Bootstrap is connected correctly

I tried this one:

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="work1_1_over" class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 float-md-right float-lg-right"></div>
    <div id="work1_2_over" class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 float-md-left float-lg-left"></div>
</div>
```

**Screenshot**

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What are you trying to do? Position the columns on the right, or the content of the columns? What is the content of the columns?

Comment: It's bootstrap 4. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/ Problem was in bootstrap.css file. It was broken. Q closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have included `bootstrap.css` in your HTML page then it should work properly. Check the below code snippet, for better convenience I have used the bootstrap class `text-center`.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
    <div id="work1_1_over" class="col-sm-12 text-center col-md-6 float-md-right float-lg-right">some Content 1</div>
    <div id="work1_2_over" class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 float-md-left float-lg-left">some Content 2</div>
</div>
```